# Manipulating multple CSV files at once

Tags: python, csv, pandas, os.walk

I am currently learning how to work with Python and for the moment I am very fond of working with CSV files. I managed to learn a few things and now I want to apply what I learned to multiple files at once. But something got me confused. I have this code:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):       
  for file in files: 
    if file.endswith(".csv"):              
         paths=os.path.join(root,file)
         tables=pd.read_csv(paths, header='infer', sep=',') 
         print(paths)
         print(tables)
```

It prints all the CSV files found in that folder in a certain format ( a kind of table with the first row being a header and the rest following under) 
The trick is that I want to be able to access these anytime (print and edit) and what I wrote there only prints them ONCE. if I write `print(paths)` or `prints(tables)` anywhere else after that it only prints the LAST CSV file and its data, even though I believe it should do the same thing.

I also tried making similar separate codes for each print (tables and paths) but it only works for the first `os.walk()` - I just don`t get why it only works once.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to store the DataFrames as you load them. Right now you are just loading and discarding.

```
dfs = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):       
  for file in files: 
    if file.endswith(".csv"):              
         paths=os.path.join(root,file)
         tables=pd.read_csv(paths, header='infer', sep=',')
         dfs.append(tables)
         print(paths)
         print(tables)
```

The above will give you a list of DataFrames `dfs` that you can then access and utilize. Like so:

```
print(dfs[0])
# prints the first DataFrame you read in.

for df in dfs:
    print(df)
# prints each DataFrame in sequence
```

Once you have the data stored you can do pretty much anything.

Comment: This works like a charm! Not even crossed my mind to use DataFrames, thank you a lot! I still have ways to learn but this helps a lot.